# Instagram API: /locations/location-id/media/recent returns empty result

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

I always get empty `JSON` response by

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/LOCATION-ID/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

e.g. `api.instagram.com/v1/locations/140831586/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`, which is for Museum of Modern Art (MoMA)

The `JSON` Response:

```
{"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

I tried some other location IDs, all of the results were empty too.
Any suggestions?

**NOTE:**
My access_token is generaged in Sandbox mode with

```
&scope=basic+public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes. It works fine for location search "/locations/search?lat=40.761397&lng=73.976986&distance=5000&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN"
```

Comment: Are you using https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/LOCATION-ID=140831586/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN or https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/140831586/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN as it's the latter.

Comment: It's latter. I revised the sample URL. Thanks

Comment: are u in sandbox mode?

Comment: Yes, my app is in Sandbox mode. But I think the access_token has the right permission (public_content) by following steps 1) get CODE by "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=basic+public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes" and 2) get ACCESS-TOKEN by "curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' -F 'redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI' -F 'code=CODE' https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: in sandbox mode, it will show only photos from user that are approved for the sandbox

Answer (score 2):

I get empty data as well and I have public_content permission. But when using following console: https://apigee.com/console/instagram I get the recent media for specific location. Nothing mentioned in documentation for Instagram API sandbox mode but I think you need a live app (although in sandbox mode all features should be available)

Update:
You can get media using app in Sandbox mode, but only media uploaded from the Sandbox Users are displayed.